# what is the best algorithm of sorting in speed

Tags: algorithm, sorting, assembly

There's bubble, insert, selection, quick sorting algorithm.

> Which one is the 'fastest' algorithm?

code size is not important.

```
Bubble sort
insertion sort
quick sort
```

I tried to check speed. when data is already sorted, bubble, insertion's Big-O is n but the algorithm is too slow on large lists.

Is it good to use only one algorithm?
Or faster to use a different mix?

Comment: It depends on... everything.  Every general property that can be explained will be explained on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: I don't think there is one answer for this. It is probably dependant on the size, type of data and more. Can you be specific on what the condition you are looking at?

Comment: If there was an undisputed winner regardless of the situation, everyone would know it and we'd forget about the others. Clearly that does not describe the world we live in.

Comment: Selection of a sorting algorithm can be a complex decision, depending on your requirements. In general, just use the sort supplied by your language's runtime library unless you have special needs.

Comment: There is no fastest algorithm just as there is no best singer.

Comment: The language is ARM assembly. Size is about 500 words and this means the type of data is character....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quicksort is generally very good, only really falling down when the data is close to being ordered already, or when the data has a lot of similarity (lots of key repeats), in which case it is slower.

If you don't know anything about your data and you don't mind risking the slow case of quick sort (if you think about it you can probably make a determination for your case if it's ever likely you'll get this (from already ordered data)) then quicksort is never going to be a BAD choice.

If you decide your data is or will sometimes (or often enough to be a problem) be sorted (or significantly partially sorted) already, or one way and another you decide you can't risk the worst case of quicksort, then consider timsort.

As noted by the comments on your question though, if it's really important to have the ultimate performance, you should consider implementing several algorithms and trying them on good representative sample data.

Answer (score 0):

HP / Microsoft std::sort is [introsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) (quick sort switching to heap sort if nesting reaches some limit), and std::stable_sort is a variation of bottom up [mergesort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

For sorting an array or vector of mostly random integers, [counting / radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) would normally be fastest.

Most [external sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) are some variation of a k-way bottom up merge sort (the initial internal sort phase could use any of the algorithms mentioned above).

For sorting a small (16 or less) fixed number of elements, a [sorting network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) could be used. This seems to be one of the lesser known algorithms. It would mostly be useful if having to repeatedly sort small sets of elements, perhaps implemented in hardware.